# Probability, choose $2$ numbers from a set

Tags: probability

Randomly choose two different numbers from $3,7,9,12,27$, one after the other.
If the first number chosen is $x$ and the second number chosen is $y$, what's the probability that $x^n = y$, where $n$ is an integer?

It might be a simply question but I can't get my answer match to the given answer which is $\frac{1}{10}$.

My approach as we can choose either $3$ for the first number and $9$ or $27$ for the second one.

Alternatively, we can have $9$ as first number and $27$ as second number.

Thus, we have $$\frac{1}{5} \times \frac{2}{4} + \frac{1}{5} \times \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{20}$$

I'm pretty sure I did something wrong here, but I can't figure it out at the moment. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

$9$ then $27$ does not satisfy $9^n=27$, so there are only $2$ of the $20$ choices that satisfy the requirment.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I just made simple stupid mistake haha.